# Is this a safe way to prevent database injection?

Tags: mysql, database, security, sql-injection

Often times I use methods like this to filter input. Using `preg_match( )` as shown, or sometimes using a `switch( )` that only acts if a POST/GET variable is one of a specific number of keywords.

```
if (preg_match("/^[0-9]+$/",$_POST['id_to_clear']))
    {
    db_query("UPDATE `table` SET `error`=0, `progress`=0 WHERE `id` = {$_POST['id']}");
    }
```

Generally speaking, using a POST/GET variable directly in an SQL query is a huge red flag. But in this case it seems perfectly safe. Is there any way this could go awry? Something I'm not seeing?

Comment: why dont use parameters? dont try to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: use prepared statements: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html

Comment: Yes, I agree with @MitchWheat use prepared statements.

Comment: "Some people, when confronted with a problem, think 'I know, I'll use regular expressions.' Now they have two problems." — [Jamie Zawinsky](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Jamie_Zawinski). It's general wisdom that query parameters are both safer to prevent SQL injection, and much easier to code than regular expression filtering solutions like the one you show.

Answer (score 2):

You should probably just use prepared statements here, and PHP offers a number of APIs which implement this.  That being said, if the following regex passes:

```
preg_match("/^[0-9]+$/", $_POST['id_to_clear'])
```

Then the `id_to_clear` POST value should contain only digits, in which case I don't see any way which the query you showed us could be injected.

But *beware*, because even though things might be safe now, in the future, your query might have a problem.  Without too much difficulty, I could imagine a refactor later on which again exposes the query to SQL injection.  So, stick with statements, unless there is a compelling reason to do otherwise.

Comment: Weird part is validate `$_POST['id_to_clear']` but then use `$_POST['id']` :/

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza That's gotta be a typo :P

Comment: Yes that was a typo, this isn't my exact code, just a very representative sample.

Comment: @l008com a "representative sample" still needs to be actual working code.  Posting something you have not verified is wasting the time of volunteers, and not consistent with how it should be done.  See 
 https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Can you give me an example of how this might not be safe later on? Because I can't think of any :/

Comment: Well someone else could inherit and refactor your code without sterilizing the input.  If you use a statement that person will probably continue to do so.